# Godaddy Domain name to azure static website mapping

Tags: azure, hosting, godaddy-api

I have taken the domain name from Godaddy.
After that, I have chosen static website in azure storage account and added one index.html in blob storage.
The page is accessible from azure's given URL https://xyz.z29.web.core.windows.net.

I want to map that URL to my Godaddy domain name. Below are the screenshot I am trying as given in blob service=> custom domain tab but not getting success.[image: Azure portal screen shot]

[image: GoDaddy portal screenshot]

I followed [it](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9c916fd1-74e8-4763-be37-6667fac7f608/how-to-configure-static-website-with-godaddy-domain-name?forum=azurecdn) but no satisfactory answer given in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `www.yourdomain.com` CNAME entry, just the `www` one. If you don't have CDN, then you don't need the `cdnverify.www...` CNAME entry either.

You could try going with the secondary solution, using the *asverify* subdomain. For this, you have to:

- Delete records you created in previous attempts
- Create a CNAME record `asverify.www` pointing to `asverify.yourstoragename.z29.web.core.windows.net`
- Wait for a short time (like 5 minutes) so your registration will go live
- On the Azure Portal, enter `asverify.www.yourdomain.com` and select the option below saying *Use indirect CNAME validation*
- Click Save

Let me know if it works or not so we can figure out what next.

Comment: very good, I had to delete the type A in GoDaddy, CNAME was my assigned azure storage url.